# Equivalent of INNER JOIN ... WHERE in NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have class `Category` that contains a `List<Subcategory>`.

Using LINQ (preferrably), I want to get *all* `Categories`s but *filter* their `Subcategorie`s such that the resulting query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM categories
LEFT JOIN subcategories ON subcategories.category_Id = categories.id WHERE subcategories.Retired = false
```

I have tried:

```
session.QueryOver<Category>()
.Left.JoinQueryOver(c => c.Subcategories, () => subcategoryAlis, s => !s.Retired)
.List<Category>())
```

And a few other hacky looking tricks but I can't seem to get the results I need. The above query produces completely useless results with the same entries appearing multiple times and many missing.

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like? A flattened list like an actual SQL join or an object graph where each category has a property with the list of related non-retired subcategories?

Comment: @JonasH Good point, I hand't thought to mention that. I am expecting the latter.

Comment: 1. Does the Subcategory expose a "Parent" property?
2. Do you need the real entities, or would a projection suffice?
3. What's the loading scenario?

Comment: @gliljas 1: No, 2: I need the entities as the whole graph will be serialized to JSON and sent to a client, 3: does 2 answer this?

Comment: Instead of filtering in the queryover statement,  add a "where" (with your subcategories alias and apply the filter) command before List<>

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used NHibernate, but I would do it with some dedicated DTO classes for converting to Json, not directly from the entities. I think something along the lines of the following linq query should work:

```
from c in session.Query<Category>
select new CategoryDto {
  Name = c.Name, //and other properties
  SubCategories = c.SubCategories
    .Where(sc => !sc.Retired)
    .Select(sc => new SubCategoryDto { ... })
    .ToList()
}
```

Comment: Actually I am already using dedicated DTOs, and automapper. The whole query in my question is wrapped in `Mapper.Map<CategoryReadDTO>()`. There *must* be a way to do this is the query...

Comment: Ah, in that case, are you aware of the ProjectTo functionality in Automapper? http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html